# Как найти количество уникальных кадров в видео | python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

У нас есть видео, которое состоит из картинок(как слайд-шоу), в них есть картинки, которые повторяются несколько раз.Как найти количество этих картинок?

Comment: Они (повторяющиеся) идут по порядку?

Comment: @MBo Нет, не по порядку

Answer (score 1):

Если количество кадров невелико, то достаточно обойти их в двойном цикле, сравнивая все пары между собой.

Если их много, то стоит для каждого кадра создать какой-то ключ, например, хэш по содержимому (возможно - не нужно полное содержимое использовать, буде достаточно, скажем, начала), и внести их в хэш-таблицу.

Подразумевается, что совпадение абсолютно точное.

Answer (score 1):

Если надо найти количество уникальных картинок в слайдшоу, то можно каждый кадр сконвертировать в `base64`, поместить в список, а потом к этому списку применить

```
len(set(image_list))
```

Но для этого все повторяющиеся картинки должны совпадать до пикселя. Если есть смещение, то лучше попробовать библиотеку `OpenCV`, чтобы каждый новый кадр сравнивать с уже добавленными в список, накладывая их друг на друга. В таком случае конвертировать в `base64` не надо.
Если же необходимо сравнить кадры в видео, то сначала надо определить моменты, когда на экране меняется кадр, поскольку каждый слайд отображается множеством кадров, и сохранять только первый кадр после каждой смены.